# Find and Insert

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that looks like (the `*` is literal):

```
clp*(seven digits)1*
```

I want to change it so that it looks like:

```
clp*(seven digits)(space)(space)1*
```

I'm working in C# and built my search pattern like this:

```
Regex regAddSpaces = new Regex(@"CLP\*.......1\*");
```

I'm not sure how to tell regex to keep the first 11 characters, add two spaces and then cap it with `1*`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @OP: check my edits; did you want those backslashes to appear in the strings, or not?  If not, why the three backslashes in the regex?

Comment: No response from the OP, but I believe this (edit #5) is how the question was supposed to read (i.e., asterisks but no backslashes).

Answer (score 6):

No need to use regex here. Simple string manipulation will do the job perfectly well.

```
var input = "clp*01234561*";
var output = input.Substring(0, 11) + "  " + input.Substring(11, 2);
```

Comment: +1. If this is indeed the complexity of the pattern, this this is a much better solution

Comment: Yeah, I wonder if the actual problem is more generic than the OP has described... Can't really add anything more at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Noldorin.  However, here's how you could do it with regular expressions if you really wanted:

```
var result = Regex.Replace("clp*12345671*", @"(clp\*\d{7})(1\*)", @"$1  $2");
```

Comment: Even though my question could have been clearer, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace this anywhere in the text you can use the excluded prefix and suffix operators...

pattern = "(?<=clp*[0-9]{7})(?=1*)"

Handing this off to the regex replace with the replacement value of "  " will insert the spaces.

Thus, the following one-liner does the trick:

`string result = Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(?<=clp\*[0-9]{7})(?=1\*)", "  ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex, but if your solution is as simple as you stated above Noldorin's answer would be a clearer and more maintainable solution.  But since you wanted regex... here you go:

```
// Not a fan of the 'out' usage but I am not sure if you care about the result success
public static bool AddSpacesToMyRegexMatch(string input, out string output)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(@"(^clp\*[0-9]{7})(1\*$)");
    Match match = reg.Match(input);
    output = match.Success ?
        string.Format("{0}  {1}", match.Groups[0], match.Groups[1]) :
        input;
    return match.Success;
}
```